# What [object global] is exactly, when "this" is accessed inside a nested or inline function?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Here is the code:

```
package {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class SomeDocumentClass extends MovieClip {

        public var abc: MovieClip;
        public var test_var = 12345;

        public function SomeDocumentClass() {
            //abc is an instance name of a movieclip placed on stage
            abc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                function () {
                    trace(this); 
                });
            abc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, abc_CLICK)
        }

        function abc_CLICK(e: Event): void {
            trace(this); 
        }

    }

}
```

The output is :

> [object global]
>
> [object SomeDocumentClass]

I also checked, `[object global]` is not even the function itself actually. Then what is it?

Comment: That is what you get in an inline function since it has no scope anywhere (it's the top level scope of the application).   Don't use inline functions, there is rarely (if ever) any benefit to using them.     Maybe this can help you understand: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous functions (also called function expressions) are *global* scoped vs. defined functions (also called function statements) *local* scoped.

**Anonymous functions**

- Cannot be used as a method
- Exists only in the scope in which it is defined
- Can only be called in the scope in which it is defined
- Can be called at any point in the code
- Can be reassigned a new value or deleted

**Defined functions**

- Can be used as a method of an object
- Exists within the object it is defined in
- Can be called at any point in the code
- Cannot be deleted or changed

**So as example:**

`this` in an Anonymous function

```
[trace] [object global]
[trace] global
[trace] <type name="global" base="Object" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
[trace]   <extendsClass type="Object"/>
[trace]   <constant name="FLASH10_FLAGS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
~~~~~~~~~~~~
[trace]   </method>
[trace] </type>
```

`this` in a Defined function

```
[trace] [object Main]
[trace] Main
[trace] <type name="Main" base="flash.display::Sprite" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
[trace]   <extendsClass type="flash.display::Sprite"/>
~~~~~~~~~~
[trace]   </metadata>
[trace] </type>
```

ActionScript cut/paste complete example:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import avmplus.getQualifiedClassName;
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        var button:CustomSimpleButton;

        public function Main() {
            button = new CustomSimpleButton();
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                    function () {
                        trace(this);
                        trace(getQualifiedClassName(this));
                        trace(describeType(this));
                    });
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
            addChild(button);
        }

        function onClickButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace(this);
            trace(getQualifiedClassName(this));
            trace(describeType(this));
        }
    }
}

import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

class CustomSimpleButton extends SimpleButton {
    private var upColor:uint   = 0xFFCC00;
    private var overColor:uint = 0xCCFF00;
    private var downColor:uint = 0x00CCFF;
    private var size:uint      = 80;

    public function CustomSimpleButton() {
        downState      = new ButtonDisplayState(downColor, size);
        overState      = new ButtonDisplayState(overColor, size);
        upState        = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, size);
        hitTestState   = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, size * 2);
        hitTestState.x = -(size / 4);
        hitTestState.y = hitTestState.x;
        useHandCursor  = true;
    }
}

class ButtonDisplayState extends Shape {
    private var bgColor:uint;
    private var size:uint;

    public function ButtonDisplayState(bgColor:uint, size:uint) {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
        this.size    = size;
        draw();
    }

    private function draw():void {
        graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```